# tsql XML DML Using the modify() method: replace value of

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have an xml column with the following data:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML
SET @XMLData = '<ArrayOfAttributeValueDO>
  <AttributeValueDO>
    <AttributeID>421</AttributeID>
    <AttributeValue>100% cotton pre-shrunk drill</AttributeValue>
  </AttributeValueDO>
  <AttributeValueDO>
    <AttributeID>422</AttributeID>
    <AttributeValue>190gsm</AttributeValue>
  </AttributeValueDO>
  <AttributeValueDO>
    <AttributeID>1221</AttributeID>
    <AttributeValue>Long Sleeve</AttributeValue>
  </AttributeValueDO>
  <AttributeValueDO>
    <AttributeID>1481</AttributeID>
    <AttributeValue>No</AttributeValue>
  </AttributeValueDO>
</ArrayOfAttributeValueDO>'
```

What's the tsql to update the text in AttributeValue tag when the AttributeID tag = 1221?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[replace value of (XML DML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml)

```
set @XMLData.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfAttributeValueDO/AttributeValueDO[AttributeID = "1221"]/AttributeValue/text())[1] with "NewValue"');
```